# Initialize java collection leaving generics blank, e.g.: HashMap<A,B> hM = HashMap<>();

Tags: java, generics, collections

I've see that since java 1.5 or maybe a later version, you can initialize  java collection leaving generics blank, i.e. using <> instead of writing out the whole < A,B >. but I can't find the official documents on this, and I'm wondering whether this has any benefits (or maybe I'm not remembering this correctly, in which case do point out the correct form). Thank you.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html). It was introduced in Java 1.7.

The benefit is just that you need to write less code.

Compare

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
```

to

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Note: This is/was a lazy specialized syntax shortcut that didn't require adding type inference. (Type inference works in the other direction.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. And what about using List instead of explicitly using ArrayList during declaration?

Comment: @DanSoren Search for 'programming to interfaces'

Comment: @DanSoren http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: In short, the diamond operator allows you to write [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) code.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called the [diamond operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html). It was introduced in Java 7.